# Resetting in-app purchase for non consumable items while testing [iOS] [Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am currently in the process of testing ***in-app purchase*** for a ***non-consumable item***. I am successfully able to make the purchase, but I want to reset the purchase made so that I can test multiple scenarios. Doing this for Android was simple by issuing a refund but I don't see a similar option of ***iOS***. Is there a way I could reset the existing purchases for a sandbox account?

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure this one out?